# A man such as yourself has acquired your own wealth vs A man such as yourself has acquired his own wealth?

Tags: grammar, usage, pronouns

A man such as yourself has acquired ***your*** own wealth
vs
A man such as yourself has acquired ***his*** own wealth?

Which one is correct? I think it's the second one, but I'm not sure

Comment: Both examples should be _A man such as you_.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I've no particular preference for one over the other in this exact context, but this NGram suggests that the reflexive version [has become *particularly* favoured in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+such+as+you%2Cman+such+as+yourself&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10) over recent decades. I have a vague sense of the reflexive version feeling a bit more "immediate", and therefore perhaps "intimate". Maybe I'm just gobbing off, but I think I might use ***yourself*** to a mate or underling, but ***you*** when talking to the boss at work.

Comment: To me, an American speaker, the phrase _a man such as yourself_ sounds ingratiating. Adding an extra, unnecessary, syllable referring to the addressee is a subtle way of stoking an ego. I would be wary of buying a used car from somebody who talked like that.

Comment: Yes! That's essentially what I think! Except I didn't necessarily take quite such a "cynical" view of the "deferential" overtones! Interestingly, the magic of NGrams suggests that both sides of the pond much prefer the reflexive version when the speaker is referring to ***himself***.  So *A native speaker [**such as myself** has](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=such+as+myself+has%2Csuch+as+me+has&year_start=1910&year_end=2010&corpus=26&smoothing=3) a strong preference for the reflexive pronoun.*

Comment: Ingratiation might be the intention.  I'd use it with a friend, for example, to lend a semi-ironic but respectful tone.  A bit like addressing your friend, generally 'Tom', as 'Mr Simmons', or 'My dear Mr Simmons'.  Formality among intimates can be mildly amusing, yet somehow also warm.

Answer (score 1):

'A man' is third person; hence, 'his'.

Comment: You should expand this to give more detail on why this is the case.

Comment: The sentence refers to a hypothetical 'man like you', not directly to 'you'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting:  Yes, precisely; 'a man' with any qualifier attached isn't 'you' (2p) or 'I' (1p), but the third-person (s)he/ it.  @ KillingTime:  Though languages exist with more than three grammatical persons, English isn't one of them.  Another clue is the verb form 'has', which can only ever be applied to the third person.  The pronoun 'your' (2p) is incorrect as it cannot apply to the subject of the sentence ('A man'... in a hat/ who lives by the sea/ such as David/ such as I - though the last, and indeed the O.P.'s example, sound a bit odd and could perhaps rephrased elsewise.